# "Install" a .patch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen you guys have made several fixes(.patch) for ROS, some that would be very useful for me, however, I can't find anything that tells me how to "install" them in my ROS Fuerte, actually I'm pretty confused even about where to put the fixes. So, how do I do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44257/%22install%22-a-.patch/) by [borth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2921/borth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-09-20**:
Could you please be more specific by giving an example?

**Comment by [borth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2921/borth/) on 2012-09-20**:
Well, https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3949 here there are some patches to use ROS with Python 3 , but how I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

patches are nothing you can simply install. Those .patch files are normally diffs of the source code (means it contains the changes to the source code that have been made to fix a bug).

So in general (I think this also applies for ROS) you need to download the ROS source code first (svn checkout) and then apply a .patch to the source code. You can read up on how to create and apply patches [here](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion).

Cheers
Felix

---

Originally posted by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) with karma: 318 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5